# How to get a widget from another app when clicking on it and paste to the clipboard?

Tags: linux, python-3.6, gtk3, paste

I am working on a program but as I'm still new to Python I don't know how to paste the content of the clipboard, which I already figured out, so I can enter some text in my GtkTextView and when clicking a button that text goes in the system clipboard, but what I'm trying to do is that when I click the button in my program to then automatically paste the clipboard to ANY other application when I click on them, like for example to Chrome or to gedit or any other 3rd party application.

I don't know how to get the text entry of say for example Chrome when clicking on it.

How do I get a widget from another app when clicking on it and paste it to the clipboard there automatically?

Comment: Anyone please help??

Comment: Sadly, the short answer is no.